# Javascript Websocket fails to receive TCP data

Tags: javascript, security, websocket, tcp

I'm trying to receive json data from an ESP32 via TCP to a website hosted thru WAMP (localhost -> ESP32 IP address on local network is 10.11.125:23). Below is my javascript function. My browser (Firefox Developer) generates a "SecurityError: The operation is insecure" when executing the line `var connection = new webSocket('ws://10.11.13.125:23')`. What am I missing??

```
function openWebsocket() {
    console.log("open Websocket.....");
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://10.11.13.125:23');

    connection.onerror = function(error) {
        $("#Connection").html("Connection Error");

        console.log("Websocket Error: " + error);
    }

    connection.onopen = function(evt) {
        $("#Connection").html("Connected");
    }

    connection.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    connection.onmessage = function(evt) {
        console.log("Server: " + evt.data.byteLength);
    }

    console.log("ReadyState: "+connection.readyState);
}
```

Comment: PS: using `var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:23/');` yields the same error / result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The Chromium browser yields a more descriptive error message. Port 23 is not available. Switched over to 
`var connection = new WebSocket('ws://10.11.13.125:80');` 
and voila, everything works as expected.

Sorry for posting about an issue that in the end I found the solution for myself.